# Convert code from BGW to Async and Await for DataTabale/MySQLDataAdapter

Tags: c#, async-await, task, backgroundworker

How can I abandon BGW and use async/wait tasking thing, I am willing to learn the technique as I am using VS 2013.

I looked at the examples online, but still I am unable to do it myself because the examples I came across were using existing functions in .NET which already return a task. I tried to separate the code inside BGW DoWork and create a task, but the compiler kept asking me about await  and I could not call the task anyway, I noticed that the lines taking time are:

```
SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd);
SQLDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

What I need is: inside a button click to start the task of reading from the database, and then relieve the Form from hanging (suppose I am not using BGW), and then read the result and displaying them in the datagridview.

```
// code starts here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace MySQLProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string stdNo = File.ReadAllText("stdNo.txt").Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");


            const string cs = @"what ever";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            MySqlDataAdapter SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(); ;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();
            this.InvokeEx(x => x.textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("MySQL version : {0};", conn.ServerVersion)));

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("StudentNamesAndNumbers");
            dt.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Student ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("First", typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add("Second", typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string));
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            try
            {

                MySqlCommand SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand();
                SQLcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                SQLcmd.CommandText = String.Format(@"Select u.firstname as 'Student Name', u.username as 'Student ID'"
                                                    + ",( select  score from gradebook_result g , gradebook_evaluation e "
                                                    + "where g.user_id = u.user_id "
                                                    + "and name = 'First' "
                                                    + "and g.evaluation_id = e.id "
                                                    + "and e.course_code = c.course_code) as 'First' "
                                                    + ",( select  score from gradebook_result g , gradebook_evaluation e "
                                                    + "where g.user_id = u.user_id "
                                                    + "and name = 'Second' "
                                                    + "and g.evaluation_id = e.id "
                                                    + "and e.course_code = c.course_code) as 'Second' "
                                                    + ", c.course_code as 'Section'"
                                                    + "from user u, course_rel_user c "
                                                    + "where "
                                                    + "u.username in ({0}) "
                                                    + "and u.username REGEXP '[0-9]+' "
                                                    + "and c.course_code like 'IT102CPLUS%' "
                                                    + "and  u.user_id = c.user_id ;", stdNo);

                this.InvokeEx(x => x.textBox1.AppendText(SQLcmd.CommandText));

                SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd);
                SQLDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Section ASC, Student Name ASC";
                this.InvokeEx(x => x.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear());
                this.InvokeEx(x => x.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["StudentNamesAndNumbers"]);
                this.InvokeEx(x => x.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns());
                this.InvokeEx(x => x.label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Students");

                // =======================================================

                var lines = new List<string>();

                string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                                  ToArray();

                var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
                lines.Add(header);

                var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));            
                lines.AddRange(valueLines);

                File.WriteAllLines("Export.csv", lines, Encoding.UTF8);

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                this.InvokeEx(x => x.textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("Error: {0}\n\n", ex.ToString())));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a [series on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) that shows how `BackgroundWorker` compares to `Task.Run`.

In general, you should not be using either of these approaches for I/O-bound operations. However, there are some older APIs that have not been upgraded to expose TAP methods. I believe the "data adapter" and "data table" APIs are considered too old to be upgraded, hence there's no "FillAsync" you could use.

So - assuming you want to keep the "data table" approach - you can just use `Task.Run` as a replacement for `BackgroundWorker` directly. Note that `IProgress<T>` is a more modern way of doing any kind of cross-thread invoking for progress updates:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    var progress = new Progress<string>(update => textBox1.AppendText(update));
    var ds = await Task.Run(() => BackgroundWork(progress));
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["StudentNamesAndNumbers"];
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
    label1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Students";
    button1.Enabled = true;
}

private DataSet BackgroundWork(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    string stdNo = File.ReadAllText("stdNo.txt").Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");

    const string cs = @"what ever";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
    MySqlDataAdapter SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(); ;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();
    if (progress != null)
        progress.Report(string.Format("MySQL version : {0};", conn.ServerVersion));

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("StudentNamesAndNumbers");
    dt.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Student ID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("First", typeof(float));
    dt.Columns.Add("Second", typeof(float));
    dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string));
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand SQLcmd = new MySqlCommand();
        SQLcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        SQLcmd.CommandText = String.Format(@"Select u.firstname as 'Student Name', u.username as 'Student ID'"
                                                + ",( select  score from gradebook_result g , gradebook_evaluation e "
                                                + "where g.user_id = u.user_id "
                                                + "and name = 'First' "
                                                + "and g.evaluation_id = e.id "
                                                + "and e.course_code = c.course_code) as 'First' "
                                                + ",( select  score from gradebook_result g , gradebook_evaluation e "
                                                + "where g.user_id = u.user_id "
                                                + "and name = 'Second' "
                                                + "and g.evaluation_id = e.id "
                                                + "and e.course_code = c.course_code) as 'Second' "
                                                + ", c.course_code as 'Section'"
                                                + "from user u, course_rel_user c "
                                                + "where "
                                                + "u.username in ({0}) "
                                                + "and u.username REGEXP '[0-9]+' "
                                                + "and c.course_code like 'IT102CPLUS%' "
                                                + "and  u.user_id = c.user_id ;", stdNo);

        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report(SQLcmd.CommandText);

        SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd);
        SQLDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Section ASC, Student Name ASC";
        var lines = new List<string>();

        string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                              Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                              ToArray();

        var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
        lines.Add(header);

        var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));            
        lines.AddRange(valueLines);

        File.WriteAllLines("Export.csv", lines, Encoding.UTF8);
        return ds;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report(string.Format("Error: {0}\n\n", ex.ToString()));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to comprehend what you wrote for about 20 minutes. Your answer reflects that your book is excellent, indeed!  ^_^  ^_^  ^_^  ^_^  I will get back to you once I finish playing with your code :-)

Comment: It works! I just replaced dt with dataGridView1 inside the button click to count the students. I tried many times to use async thing, but I did not know I had to use async with the button_click handler as well. BTW, what did you mean by "data table" approach, what else can I do?

Comment: @elekgeek: Most developer shops these days either use some form of ORM (Entity Framework, NHibernate, or any of a few dozen small ones), or else they just use ADO directly. Data tables and adapters have some pretty hefty memory and performance overheads, especially with large data sets.

Comment: The problem is that when I searched on how to MySQL and C#, most people were doing it with either DataAdapter or DataReader. I 've never heard of ORM, Entity Framework, NHibernate. I will do more search on these, thanks.

Comment: How can I add rows one by one to the datagrid and update a progressbar?

Comment: @elekgeek: I would have an `IProgress<T>` with `T` containing the information you need for a row.

Comment: but there is no way to track the progress of filling the dataviewgrid. I don't even know what I am going to report in the IProgress<T>.

Comment: @elekgeek: It's very difficult for me to know the correct answer to that without knowing how your code will change. Could you post another question with your code loading a single row at a time from the db?

Comment: aha... I spent the day before trying to figure how I will fill the datagrid from datasource row by row (I have  this idea already, row by row) and it's not easy to convert DataRow to DataGridViewRow. I tried many ways, but non of them succeeded. Most people here were showing easy examples of BGW/Async which just show for loops, but questions about this issue were never really answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the method as `async` and await async method when you can.
If there is no async method and you want to run the synchronous method on another thread, await on  `Task.Run`.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            //Use an async method when there is one available
            string stdNo;
            using (var reader = File.OpenText("Words.txt"))
            {
                stdNo = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            stdNo = stdNo.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");

            const string cs = @"what ever";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            MySqlDataAdapter SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(); ;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //Use Task.Run to call a long running code on another thread
            //If available you should use await conn.OpenAsync();
            await Task.Run(() => conn.Open());
            //You don't need invoke, after an await you are back to the synchronization context
            textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("MySQL version : {0};", conn.ServerVersion));

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("StudentNamesAndNumbers");
            dt.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Student ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("First", typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add("Second", typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string));
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            //...
        }
        finally
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why would you do it on conn.Open(), the connection opening doesn't take time, the actual job is in `SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd);` and 
`SQLDataAdapter.Fill(dt);` anyway, how can I do it on those two lines?

Comment: `the connection opening doesn't take time` You don't know how long it can take, network timeout is often 60sec. You just have to apply the same logic to other calls.

Comment: @Guillaume You could use `await conn.OpenAsync();` which is truly asynchronous'

Comment: can I do this: `await Task.Run(() => SQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd));`

Comment: var myAdapter = await Task.Run(() => new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd));